# Согласны с объяснением написания?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сравнительный-оборот

*Иван много читал(,) как его отец*.

В данном случае запятая может ставиться, а может и не ставиться, в зависимости от контекста предложения. Если нам важно много или мало читал Иван, и упор ставится именно на это, то запятая ставится, т.к. присутствует значение уподобления, без обстоятельственных оттенков (Отец Ивана читал много, и Иван тоже читает много, подобно своему отцу). 
Но также запятая может и не ставится в случае, если, например, из контекста мы узнаем, что отец Ивана обладал какой-то особой техникой чтения, следовательно оборот *как его отец* приобретет обстоятельственный оттенок образа действия, и в этом случае *много читал* уже не будут нести должной смысловой нагрузки.

Полёт мысли ясен? Согласны с объяснением?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очевидный смысл предложения в том, что для Ивана интенсивное чтение - семейная традиция, идущая от отца. Либо просто они с отцом в этом похожи. Я вижу только один вариант написания предложения с таким смыслом - для складности в нём не хватает союза "и", который снял бы вопрос о факультативности запятой:

> Иван много читал, как **и** его отец.

"Полёт мысли" *допускает* и варианты без запятой, однако, соответствующие такой пунктуации контексты либо оказываются фантастичными, либо делают неуклюжим выражение нового смысла. Посмотрим, какой смысл можно подвести под предложение с такой пунктуацией:

> Иван много читал как его отец.

Варианты подходящего контекста ведут к странным ситуациям:

1. Иван - отец человека, на которого ссылаются местоимением "его". Будучи его отцом, по праву отца он "много читал". Какие же контексты здесь правдоподобны? Вероятно, он читал в каких-нибудь архивах множество материалов по делу безвременно ушедшего сына. Либо этот ушедший сын его был вундеркиндом-писателем, и отец выступал на неких литературных чтениях памяти сына, а читать ему (*как отцу, в качестве отца*) досталось больше, чем другим участникам.
2. Отец Ивана обладал уникальной манерой художественного чтения. Иван на конкурсе чтецов многие фрагменты читал в манере своего отца (читал как?).
3. Иван выдавал себя за своего отца и читал много материалов, к которым отец имел специальный допуск (в качестве кого, под чьим именем читал много из того?). Это и фантастично по смыслу, и неуклюже стилистически.

Поэтому остаётся вариант с запятой и союзом "и".